# How would I go about pulling the most popular (most used) categories?

Tags: categories

I am trying to use WordPress' built in function for calling a list of categories. Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be an argument for how to pull the most popular categories (say top 5). I am using the code below which is pulling in all categories. Any idea on how I could modify this to display the top 5 most used categories?

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
    'show_option_all'    => '',
    'orderby'            => 'name',
    'order'              => 'ASC',
    'style'              => 'list',
    'show_count'         => 0,
    'hide_empty'         => 1,
    'use_desc_for_title' => 1,
    'child_of'           => 0,
    'feed'               => '',
    'feed_type'          => '',
    'feed_image'         => '',
    'exclude'            => '1',
    'exclude_tree'       => '',
    'include'            => '',
    'hierarchical'       => 1,
    'title_li'           => __( '' ),
    'show_option_none'   => __( '' ),
    'number'             => 5, // limits the number of displayed categories
    'echo'               => 1,
    'depth'              => 0,
    'current_category'   => 0,
    'pad_counts'         => 0,
    'taxonomy'           => 'category',
    'walker'             => null,
    );
    wp_list_categories( $args );
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can order by `count` to order them by the number of posts they are attached to. Use `number` to limit the number of terms returned:

```
wp_list_categories( [
    'orderby' => 'count',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'number' => 5
] );
```

Comment: Wow I am feeling very humbled right now. I looked at the WP documentation for this function and missed this. Thank you!

Comment: Don't feel so bad, I don't think `count` is listed anywhere as a valid value for `orderby`, you have to look at the documentation for the generic `get_terms` to see that it's possible to do this.

Comment: Just want to throw in that unsurprisingly this query string also works for get_categories()/get_terms()! Thanks so much for this solution, I had no idea it was possible! `$terms = get_categories(array('orderby' => 'count', 'order' => 'DESC', 'number' => 10));`